# Example For ThreadPool in JAVA

Tags: java, threadpool

Can anybody give me simple example in which we have created our own threadpool class to get better feel of the threads. I don't want to use Executor Service available in java. I mean any inbuilt class for the threadpool.

Thanks

Comment: Executors are part of the Java SE library. Why don't you want to use them? They present a _much_ more useful API for managing threads.

Comment: I read parts of this.. and it has a self built example with all the things you will have to deal with.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be what you're looking for. 
http://java.dzone.com/news/java-concurrency-thread-pools

```
public class ThreadPool {

  private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null;
  private List<PoolThread> threads = new ArrayList<PoolThread>();
  private boolean isStopped = false;

  public ThreadPool(int noOfThreads, int maxNoOfTasks){
    taskQueue = new BlockingQueue(maxNoOfTasks);

    for(int i=0; i<noOfThreads; i++){
      threads.add(new PoolThread(taskQueue));
    }
    for(PoolThread thread : threads){
      thread.start();
    }
  }

  public void synchronized execute(Runnable task){
    if(this.isStopped) throw
      new IllegalStateException("ThreadPool is stopped");

    this.taskQueue.enqueue(task);
  }

  public synchronized void stop(){
    this.isStopped = true;
    for(PoolThread thread : threads){
      thread.stop();
    }
  }

}



public class PoolThread extends Thread {

  private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null;
  private boolean       isStopped = false;

  public PoolThread(BlockingQueue queue){
    taskQueue = queue;
  }

  public void run(){
    while(!isStopped()){
      try{
        Runnable runnable = (Runnable) taskQueue.dequeue();
        runnable.run();
      } catch(Exception e){
        //log or otherwise report exception,
        //but keep pool thread alive.
      }
    }
  }

  public synchronized void stop(){
    isStopped = true;
    this.interrupt(); //break pool thread out of dequeue() call.
  }

  public synchronized void isStopped(){
    return isStopped;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone ... :) Actually i want to get the feeling of the Threadpool. I want to know the inner working like how the threads are picked ( wait and notify) and alloted the task.